# CSS overflow auto not working

Tags: asp.net, css

This is the structure

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <asp:panel runat="server">
      <asp:Gridview runat="server">
      </asp:Gridview>
    </asp:panel>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I would like the div, fieldset and panel widths to stay intact. When the columns in the grid increase, a scrollbar should appear for the panel.
I am unable to figure that out. The panel & grid are going out of the fieldset.

http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/12/

Comment: use overflow-x:visible or scroll

Answer (score 1):

give the width property a value along with it..!!

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server style="overflow-x:auto;width:760px">
```

**EDIT:** if you need to give width:100% then do

```
<asp:Panel runat="server style="overflow-x:auto;width:100%">



     .fieldset
        {
            border:1px solid gray;
            border-radius:5px;
            overflow-x:auto;
        }
        .div
{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Latest**
jsfiddle-[working css as you need](http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/20/)

Comment: I dont think, pixels would be a good option right? What if the viewing screen size varies?

Comment: @Ruby thats not a problem..!! we have css3 mediaqueries "@media (max-width:value)" property for the screen width changes..!! [css3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: @Ruby for your problem..!! you must give width property a value..!! let it be in percentage or pixel..!! i think you got it work with my solution..!!

Comment: <asp:Panel runat="server style="overflow-x:auto;width:100%;max-width:100%">.........No Luck

Comment: @Ruby what about width in pixels..!!

Comment: Sry but pixels is not an option for me.

Comment: @Ruby: then try changing the overflow:hidden to overflow:auto in css of .div or .fieldset as your requirement..!! it works for me..!! please try and tell me..!!

Comment: i have re-edited my answer..!! it certainly works for me in check[http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/13/)

Comment: Thank You. But Not the way I wanted. I want the scroll to be for the blue div. The blue div and the table are moving out of the fieldset. Wasnt it obvious.

Comment: then,this is exactly what u need..!!check this-[http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/20/](http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/20/)

Comment: @Ruby i would like to get a response from you..!!

Answer (score 1):

To make your property `overflow:auto` work try to set a `max-width` or fixed `width` too

```
<asp:Panel runat="server style="width:100%; max-width:100%; overflow-x:auto;">
```

**EDIT**

After review your code finally i get what is the problem, for default it's been assigned a `min-width` for your `fieldset` that fits his contain. Then additional to the definitions of `width` and `max-width` i set a `min-width`

```
.fieldset
 {
  display:block;
  width:93%;
  max-width:93%;
  min-width:0%;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:2%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

Check the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/29/**

PD: Be carefull with the widths remember also `padding` and `border` make it increase. Or use `box-sizing`.

Comment: can you make a fiddle with your issue?

Comment: Hi I tried. But it suprisingly seems no issue with html in the fiddle. Hence I did not go for it

Comment: mmm it's impossible to guess that way without seen the problem :(

Comment: Thank you. Guess Im close. The Xscroll is now in the fieldset.Its just that I want it to the div with class grid. And plz explain Width 120%

Comment: Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/FksxS/12/ As you can see, the table goes out of fieldsetm &  i want to place the Xscroll for the blue div